# Icon animation when hovered

Tags: html, css, animation, button, navbar

[image: new update]I wan the arrows on my navbar to produce the animation I've created when I hover the options on top of them, [image: See this]

When my mouse hovers "contact", "register" or "login", the arrows under them should move down indicating that they are dropdown buttons, how can I do this? I already have the code of the animation but I don't know how to sync this code with my buttons, I would appreciate any help. Here's the code:

```css
#arrow1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 11%;
  left: 83.5%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 15px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 110px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: yellow;
}

#arrow1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  animation: animate 1s;
  right: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@keyframes animate {
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-8px);
    margin-top: -35px;
  }
}

#arrow2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 11%;
  left: 66%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 15px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 110px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: yellow;
}

#arro2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  animation: animate 1s;
  right: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@keyframes animate {
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-8px);
    margin-top: -35px;
  }
}

#arrow3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 11%;
  left: 48.7%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 15px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 110px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: yellow;
}

#arrow3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  animation: animate 1s;
  right: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@keyframes animate {
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-8px);
    margin-top: -35px;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="inicio"><a href="#">INICIO</a></li>
  <li id="contacto"><a href="#">CONTACTO</a></li>
  <li id="registrate"><a href="#">REGISTRATE</a></li>
  <li id="ingresar"><a href="#">INGRESAR</a></li>
  <div class="circle">
    <i class="fas fa-angle-down" id="arrow1"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-angle-down" id="arrow2"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-angle-down" id="arrow3"></i>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is very irresponsive. You're hardcoding the positions and they might not work if you resize your browser's window.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to all this, can you please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm bored so I made this for you, I think it's almost what you want: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pLzENO

Comment: It's exactly what I want! Thank you sir! Here's your +1

Comment: I've copied the code to my notepad but it's not working for me, check out the image I've to my question, my navbar went crazy

Comment: I'll create an answer. THe thing is, the CSS part in this codepen is SCSS. To get it right, click on the arrow and click "show compiled css"

Comment: Perfect, it's fixed, now I would like to remove the arrow from under "inicio" what part should I remove of the code?

Comment: In that case, you should add a class to every `li` that you want to have an arrow (something like `with-arrow`). And in the css, change the `li` selector to `li.with-arrow`.

Comment: Done, now last but not least, if you don't mind, I would like to know how to remove these 3 mini arrows that appear on the top of my navbar, check the image that I added, you're my hero btw

Comment: Those arrows are there probably because you haven't removed the `circle` div

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. Thanks again! You saved my day.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have your animation assigned to each arrow ID, that animation is playing on page load.

To have the animation play *only* when the cursor is hovering over the element, you need to add a :hover pseudo-class to each arrow and add the animation within that block.

```css
#arrow1:hover {
  animation: animate 1s;
}
```

After doing that, you should have something like this:

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #151515;
}

#container,
.navItem {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.navItem {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navItem:hover .arrow {
  animation: animate 1s;
}

.navText {
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  color: #ffff4c;
  bottom: -15px;
}

@keyframes animate {
  50% {
    transform: translateY(8px);
    margin-top: -35px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="navItem">
    <div class="navText">
      Contacto
    </div>
    <i class="fas fa-angle-down arrow"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

You may notice that I also edited the HTML and CSS for that example, but the idea is the same. This brings me to my next point, and something that may help you.

## Classes

Using ID's is a perfectly acceptable way to write your markup and use CSS to style; however, using `id` as opposed to `class` can be cumbersome. Since you have multiple arrows, I would advise using classes as opposed to ID's.

So, all of your arrows would be assigned a class. In my example, I used a simple `.arrow` class. This is proper CSS styling. ID's are unique and should only be used sparingly, usually only once in a document. Classes are reused.

I should also note that this is purely a syntactical thing. CSS will treat ID's and classes similarly if you require it.

## Transitions

You may have also noticed that the animation in my example stops if you hover away from the `navItem`. This is expected behavior if using a :hover pseudo-class on an element. A workaround is substituting an animation for a transition.

Transitions are an alternate way to apply animated properties to elements. They will animate 'forward' and 'backward' on, say, pseudo-classes like `:hover` and `:focus`.

Here's what that example looks like with a transition in place of an animation.

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #151515;
}

#container,
.navItem {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.navItem {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navItem:hover .arrow {
  transform: translateY(8px);
}

.navText {
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  color: #ffff4c;
  bottom: -15px;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="navItem">
    <div class="navText">
      Contacto
    </div>
    <i class="fas fa-angle-down arrow"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

So this gives you a much smoother interaction when hovering over a menu.

## Pseudo Elements

Lastly, I want to touch up on using Pseudo Elements for things like icons. They're useful for adding additional children to a parent element, without affecting your written markup.

We can replace the arrows with a pseudo-element to clean up our HTML, as well as creating a more manageable workspace. Here's that example, again, but using a pseudo-element in place of HTML for the arrow.

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #151515;
}

#container,
.navItem {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.navItem {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navItem:hover .navText::after {
  transform: translateY(8px);
}

.navText {
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

.navText::after {
  content: "\f107";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #FFFF00;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="navItem">
    <div class="navText">
      Contacto
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Conclusion

Should you have any further questions, I'd be happy to answer them and go more in depth.

I also leave you with this final example via Codepen:
https://codepen.io/jeffheral/pen/NYKbZq

The HTML tags may not be what you want, but feel free to change them. The important thing is we have a solid setup of ID's and classes. If you want to add more navigation items, you only need to add more HTML to your document.

Comment: Thank you so much for all this information! I'll be coming back to this question several times in the future tu review this answer to clear out my doubts! Again thank you, I really appreciate your effort.

Comment: It's my pleasure, Leon. Happy to help. I would also recommend adding MDN (Mozilla Development Network) to your list of resources.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS

Answer (score 0):

Instead of targetting every arrow individually, you can use a more generic solution:

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #444;
}
.menu li {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.menu li:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  content: '\f107';
  display: inline-block;
  color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}
.menu li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.menu li:hover:after {
  transform: translate(-50%, 5px);
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>INICIO</li>
  <li>CONTACTO</li>
  <li>REGISTRATE</li>
  <li>INGRESAR</li>
</ul>
```